# How to write generic mysql query in java

Tags: java

I had tried a Query in generic Way i.e; i want to send data from one table to another table in generic way and my query is:

```
    Statement mystmt=myConn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = mystmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM empdetails");
     ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
     int columnCount=rsmd.getColumnCount();
     int i=1,j=1;
     while(j<=columnCount && i<=columnCount )
     {
         arr1[i]= rsmd.getColumnName(j);
         System.out.println(arr1[i]);
         i++;
         j++;
     } 
     int k=1;

     System.out.println(mystmt.executeUpdate("insert into table2(srccol_name,srccol_data)select 'empno',"+arr1[k]+" from empdetails"));
```

And Here the problem is in srccol_name (i.e;'empno'), i had hardcoded the columnName.
can anybody give solution for that.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why is `empno` in single quotes if you intend it to be a column name?

Comment: I am not really sure about what you are asking. Can't you build the string using some variable instead of hardcoding it?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are writing as generic sql. Just remove quotes from that particular column. It should work.

For Ex: `insert into table2(srccol_name,srccol_data) select empno,"+arr1[k]+" from empdetails`

So, in runtime you are query will become like `insert into table2(srccol_name,srccol_data) select empno, second_column_name from empdetails`

Answer (score 0):

If i remove Quote and write Query like 
insert into table2(srccol_name,srccol_data)select empno,"+arr1[k]+" from empdetails
Then the output will be

### Table2

### srccol_name   |    srccol_data

101                   101
102                   102
103                   103

### 104                   104

But the output should be

### Table2

### srccol_name    |   srccol_data

empno               101
empno               102
empno               103
empno               104

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit your question to include this additional information and then delete this answer.